# Set two floating <div>'s to same height

Tags: css, dynamic, css-float, positioning

So i am struggling again with css positioning.

Minutes ago, i figured out that floating elements do not affect the height of their parent-container. So how do i set two `div's` which are floating to the same height when said height is dynamic?

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/qbaJ8/

How do i set the height of the cyan `<div>` to the same height as the dynamic filled green one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

.start-page-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

.first-section {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbaJ8/1/)

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can use `display: table` for parent element and `display: table-cell` instead of `float: left` for childs. It will not work in IE7. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbaJ8/7/)

Comment: Thank you! Can we say that it is a good idea to add this pro-forma to everything?

Comment: Unfortunately, i got the issue that this only works if overflow:hidden is applied. Which again causes the box to not show every element it contains

Comment: Yes. You can override later, if you need to, depending on your needs.

Comment: In this case I think you'll need to use javascript. Take a look at edit.