# MVC/Razor/HTML Same background color on vertical tiled window

Tags: html, css

I have the following view running on Razor/MVC:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="treewindow">

            <div class="treewindowtitle">
                TREEWVIEW TITLE
            </div>

            <div class="treewindowcontent">

                <div id="EquipmentTree">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Equip Class1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>Equip1.1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a>Equip1.2</a></li>
                                        <li><a>Equip1.3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a>Equip Class2</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a>Equip2.1</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <p>Left Text 1</p>
        <p>Left Text 2</p>
        <p>Left Text 3</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to have a left positioned treeview control in order to navigate and on the right side of main screen the data that will appear according to the treeview selection. This code is done in that way as some data is loaded dinamically (all logic was removed to isolate the problem I have).

I´m using the following .css file:

```
html 
{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: .85em;
    border-top: solid 5px #000;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI' , Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #000066;
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
}

a {
    color: #000066;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}


/* Treeview control
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.treewindow
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    color: #495677;
    background-color: #efeeef;
}

.treewindowtitle
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #495677;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: smaller;
}

.treewindowcontent
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    color: #495677;
    background-color: #efeeef;
}
```

My problem is to keep same background color on both screens. It happens that when the window opens at left it destroys right side of screen background. You can see that here at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cox123456a/FrBsw/): I want both sides to have same background color.

Hope someone can help me with that...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible techniques you might give a try:

1) Use Javascript (or jQuery or what have you) to equalize the heights of each containing div. For example, see this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IFuzADo/1/).

2) Retool your html so that either:

- it uses one of the layout techniques that you'd [find here](https://www.google.com/search?q=One%20True%20Layout).
- sets heights to 100%, like in [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187018/set-two-floating-divs-to-same-height).
- remove the floats and use `table-cell`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586277/css-making-two-divs-equal-height-with-display-table).

I prefer that last one whenever possible. Hope this helps!